# URL rewrite with .htaccess for login and profile system

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I have a website where the url is `localhost/project/profile.php?user=username`and I am trying to get the url to look like this: `localhost/project/username`

The most I am able to do is get rid of the `.php` by using the following code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

but that is not what I need right now.
Here is the code that is meant to be changing the url - I got it off of another thread.

```
Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]
```

but it obviously doesn't work.

I need to be able to go to the url: `localhost/project/username` and it registers as the original URL `localhost/project/profile.php?user=username`

** THE ANSWER **

Thanks to **Howlin**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /project/profile\.php\?user=(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /project/%2\? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !user=
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /project/profile.php?user=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Is your application root resides in `/project` folder?

Comment: I think you're asking where the project resides. yes it does reside in the `/project` folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /project/profile\.php\?user=(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /project/%2\? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !user=
RewriteRule ^project/(.*)$ /project/profile.php?user=$1 [L]
```

The above will change `project/profile.php?user=username` to `project/username` and it will load the information from the `project/profile.php?user=username` page

EDIT:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /project/profile\.php\?user=(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /project/%2\? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !user=
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /project/profile.php?user=$1 [L]
```

Comment: now if I type `localhost/project/josh` it says it cannot find `/profile.php` but if I type `http://localhost/project/profile.php?user=josh` it does not rewrite the URL?

Comment: but now I am trying to implement it in another project, in a sub folder, it does not want to work? so it is in `project/login/profile.php` ? then it says it cannot find the profile.php page again, even if I try and load the index.php page that does exist

Comment: trying to load other pages brings up error pages now, like if I go to `logout.php`, it gives me my 404 page

Comment: The code should only redirect anything after `project/` to `project/profile.php?user=` for files and documents that do no exist.

Comment: So I cannot access any other files? because I need to use alot of other files such as `index.php`, `logout.php`, etc.

Comment: They do, but it says they say the page could not be found

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Options FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /project/

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ profile\.php?user=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Unfortunately it still has the url: `http://localhost/project/profile.php?user=josh`

Comment: What URL you are entering in your address bar?

Comment: @user3241507 You should enter it like this `localhost/project/josh` so it will be map to `localhost/project/profile.php?user=josh` internally.

Comment: gives me a 404 not found - the requested URL /project/josh was not found on this server.

Comment: @user3241507 Try now please.

Comment: if I go to `localhost/project/profile.php?user=josh` then it does not rewrite the url, but if I go to another page like `login.php` it thinks that that is a username, not a page. going to `localhost/project/josh` works though